# SQL Multi-Location inventory DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a DB where in one table it holds store location information like location ID, address info, and a column for the inventory:

| Location_ID | paint_inventory | address info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | red,blue,black | address stuff |
| 1002 | blue,orange | address stuff |

The database also has a table that gives each paint an ID:

| paint_ID | color_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 2 | blue |
| 3 | purple |
| 4 | black |
| 5 | orange |

How can I efficiently store this information where the location table looks like this (using an ID to reference the color info in the other table):

| Location_ID | paint_inventory | address info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1,2,4 | address stuff |
| 1002 | 2, 5 | address stuff |

NOTE:
I have seen posts where people say storing information in a delimited string is poor practice, however, I am basically recreating an already existing DB and the first location table is how the data is formatted.

UPDATE:
To rephrase a little: how could I efficiently store the paint_inventory column? I was given the data as it is in the first table and my only thought of how to store this is the way I provided (Once again I understand you should never store data as a delimited string but this is how I was given the data)

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: You need to re-factor this and make it into proper, relational tables.  I also think you may be confusing  "storing" with displaying.  If the paint ID is a separate lookup table, then you would need to query that, not insert into the location table.  In reality things are backwards, the location table should have the paint ID in it, not the color name.

Comment: at the bottom I noted that the data was given to me like that @ jarlh , and @OldProgrammer :In the old DB it was setup having the paint name in the Location Table, I am trying to set it up like it is in the last shown table where the ID is displayed instead. So, in the Paint_ID table it stores all the possible paints, then in the Location Table it displays a list of paints available at the corresponding location

Comment: if I was not given the data like this, how would I go about storing that data? @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

You should create a joining table -- that table would look like this

```
id          int     --  unique generated id for relationship
paint_id    int     -- pointer to the paint
location_id int     -- pointer to the location
```

I like to call the tables by the things they join ordered alphabetically so I would call this table location_paint

There might be additional information for a can of paint at a location you could put in this table -- how full it is, when it was purchased, when it was used up, etc.

There could also be meta data in the table -- when the record was created when it was edited, who created it -- etc.

Comment: so would the join table create an ID and instance for each time a paint_id shows up in the location table? so for each location that blue paint is available at it will create an ID for that instance? so if blue is at location #s 1,3,7 it will create 3 IDs in the join table?

Comment: l@devfun41 -- yes.  you need unique ids in the join table or there is no way to work with them.  Lets say someone no longer has the paint at location 3 -- if there is no unique id in the join table there is no way to specify which record to delete.  Don't worry -- it does not take much space.